# Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible server logs not working

Tags: azure, azure-database-postgresql

I am trying to run logs for Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible server, but I keep on getting this in the image below, what could be the solution?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access the logs, we need to enable diagnostic settings on the Postgres server.   Here are the necessary steps to take.

**Step1:**
[image]

**Click on "Add Diagnostic setting"**

[image]

Enter **name** and click on **respective log services**, click on **save**

[image]

**Verification:**

Goto **Monitor** -> **logs** and run the query

[image]